# How do I delete a message once it's been sent discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

## The start

Hello everyone, this may sound/look like this question has been asked before on stack overflow but it hasn't. I've been looking around for a while and been reading documentation yet I still don't understand/don't know how to implement the thing i'm talking about into my code.

## The problem

I have a problem where on discord I am trying to see if a user sent a message which has m!verify in it and after they send that message in 0.5 seconds (i.e) the message is deleted. I've looked around and seen similar questions like these but none of them solve my problem.

## The code

```
module.exports = class VerifyCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('verify', 'tools', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("I require the \`MANAGE_ROLES\` permission to execute this command!")

    const roleMember = message.guild.roles.cache.get("860636844618154034");
    const roleVerified = message.guild.roles.cache.get("860636743564918844");

    await message.member.roles.add(roleMember).catch(err => console.log(err));
    await message.member.roles.add(roleVerified).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

What I want is something like this (pseudocode)

```
if(user sent this message m!verify) {
setTimeout({
   message.bulkDelete("m!verify")
}, 1000)
}
```

Note: Linking any documentation or tutorials that have the EXACT same answer I'm looking for (in the comments and not as an answer) would be really useful. (I promise I have looked at lots of documentation) :). I am also using slappey to generate my commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `<message>.delete`, docs found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete).  The benefit of this is its optional `options` parameter which has a built-in `setTimeout` for how long to wait before deleting the message.

In your specific case of deleting the message object that initiated the command after half a second, you can simply use `message.delete({ timeout: 500 })`.

Comment: I'll see the documentation and try to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be deleted within a certain time: `message.delete({ timeout: 500})`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but I received the exact same answer. Thank you :)